# Include a script after a custom form has been submitted

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

My case is the following:

I need to output in the document a google analytics script after a custom contact form has been submitted, i have thought about many things like:

- observers.
- layout handles
- using javascript ( this didn't worked)

How can I achieve this?

More details: After successful send, the controller doues a page redirect to the same url also outputs a success message.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to output a google script code or any script after a custom form has been saved, this controller makes a redirect to the same page and output a success message, used this function:

```
$output = $cms->setBlockId('my-custom-block')->toHtml();
$this->messageManager->addSuccess($output);
```

The addSuccess($msg) function does not strip any html tag,I can insert a "p","script" tag without problems in the custom block content.